# Unix mail command queues but does not send

Tags: email, unix

I have created a service that is supposed to send an automated email in HTML format by using UNIX mail command. It was working correctly until yesterday when suddenly stopped sending mails.

This is the command Im running programmatically

```
cat ./email.txt  | mail -v -s "$(echo -e "Report for Last Week
Content-Type: text/html
Reply-to: abraham@corp.com
From: abraham@corp.com")"  abraham@corp.com manolo@corp.com
```

The output looks like:

```
abraham@corp.com... queued 
manolo@corp.com... queued
```

I am not getting any email, neither my partner...

I am not even able to run

```
echo "test"|mail -s "This is a test" abraham@corp.com
```

Im running on RedHat Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs help. The issue was related to the sendmail service of the OS.

I had to go `service sendmail restart`

It was as simple as that, however, I did compare the configuration files against a clean machine to make sure they were similar.